# Git isn't detected inside dev container in visual studio code

Tags: git, docker-desktop, vscode-devcontainer

Git is not detected when I open dev container in VisualStudio Code even when I cloned the file from GitHub using SSH key.

Docker Desktop is working fine, also Everything is working fine as I can perform build, clean and test.
I cannot commit changes because there is not git repository.

No Git in DevContainer:
[image: shows no git]

Local filesystem with cloned files:
[image: cloned file]

I'm new to this. If anyone can help.

Comment: Which images is the devcontainer using? The devcontainer needs to have `git` installed. The terminal will only have access to programs installed in the container, not your host machine. That's kind of the whole point of the container.

Comment: Could you show us your devcontainer.json and the related Dockerfile?

Answer (score 5):

Developping inside a container means you need to [Open a Git repository or GitHub PR in an isolated container volume#](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_quick-start-open-a-git-repository-or-github-pr-in-an-isolated-container-volume), in order for your container filesystem to mount the right local folder (the one with a `.git` in it)

[image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/docs/remote/containers/architecture-containers.png]

> Start VS Code and run `Remote-Containers: Clone Repository in Container Volume...` from the Command Palette (F1).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue if your Git repo is actually a submodule, because git can't find the actual `.git` directory (it isn't mounted in the Docker image).

If you go to Output->Git, you'll see a load of messages like

```
2023-09-19 10:18:14.820 [info] > git rev-parse --show-toplevel [1ms]
2023-09-19 10:18:14.820 [info] fatal: not a git repository: /workspaces/your_submodule/../../../.git/modules/path/to/your_submodule
```

I suspect there is no easy solution, other than cloning it separately.